# JPanel not visible in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JPanel which dynamically allocates buttons in a vertical layout. The problem is when I place this panel inside JScrollPane, the scrollPane appears vertically above my buttons. I'm not sure why this is happening. Here's the code:

```
public static void GUI ()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(GAME_TITLE);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,600));
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

    Menu theMenu = new Menu();
    theMenu.setLayout(new GridLayout(mSize,0));
    theMenu.setOpaque(true);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(theMenu,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    frame.add(scroll);

    theMenu.createGameButtons(frame);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I've tried quite a few things with no success. Also, I'm attaching a link to a screen shot

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TFi7rho.png]

Comment: The bug is in the code that is not visible. The bug is in the method `createGameButtons`. There, the buttons are created and added to the frame instead of adding them to the Menu itself (which I guess is a subclass of `JPanel`). Why passing the frame to `createGameButtons()` anyway...

Comment: Is that `Menu` class is your JPanel.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Thanks guys! Christian nailed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian Hujer answered the question with:

> The bug is in the code that is not visible. The bug is in the method `createGameButtons`. There, the buttons are created and added to the frame instead of adding them to the Menu itself (which I guess is a subclass of `JPanel`)

Comment: That's (one of the reasons) why we urge people to post an MCVE.. ;)